# Working with two git repos on same server but without a bare-repo

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push, git-fetch

I've been working for a while with git and multiple remote repos, cloned form a bare-repo. So, I could commit changes on one repo, push to the bare and fetch/merge into the other repo.

On a new, small project, I was developing on a single local repo in directory "projectx". I just decided to create a new development repo on the same server, different diretory called "dev". I cloned the repo from "prod" into directory "dev". I made some changes in "dev" and commited them.

I now wanted to copy the changes from "dev" into "prod", but git refused to to the push. I read about `receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead`, but I'm unsure this is the best way.

Is this just a bad idea and I'd be better off creating a bare repo in this case too? Or is there a way to work on one repo, commit, and eventually "copy" to the other repo?

Comment: Why exactly are you using separate repos for this instead of branches?

Comment: Why not pull instead of push? Git is mostly pull-oriented.

Comment: @JimRedmond Two repositories because this is web application. Need a dev and a prod site (two domains). Branches on one repo would not allow testing without impact on the prod site.